# How can I use fprintf to write text from a TEdit control to a file in C++Builder 10.1

Tags: c++builder, c-strings, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I'm pretty sure this worked in an earlier version of C++Builder but now I need to figure out the easiest way to get this to work in C++Builder 10.1.

```
fprintf(out, "%s\n", Edit1->Text);
```

I have no idea why, but right now it seems to be writing only the first character of the text in Edit1 to the file.

Also if anyone has a link to a good source for best practices for dealing with strings C++Builder 10.1, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading it seems the solution is pretty easy.

`fwprintf(out, L"%s\n", Edit1->Text);`

What I find most odd is, as near as I can tell, the Text property doesn't have a type.  How are you supposed to know work with it when it has no type?

Comment: "*the Text property doesn't have a type*" - yes, it does: `System::String`, which is an alias for `System::UnicodeString` in 10.1. There is no such thing as "no type" in C++ (except when dealing with type erasures via `void*` pointers or `std::any`). The `%s` placeholder in `fwprintf()` expects a `wchar_t*` pointer, so use `Edit1->Text.c_str()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pretty sure this worked in an earlier version of C++Builder

Maybe, but only in pre-CB2009 versions, where the `Text` was an `AnsiString` (since CB2009, it is now a `UnicodeString`), and only as a fluke of *undefined behavior*, since you can't pass an `(Ansi|Unicode)String` object to `fprintf()` to begin with, it expects a pointer to a C-style character string instead. The sole data member of an `AnsiString` is a `char*`,  and the sole data member of a `UnicodeString` is a `wchar_t*`/`char16_t*` on Windows/Posix (respectively).

> now I need to figure out the easiest way to get this to work in C++Builder 10.1.

You have a few choices:

- cast the `Text` to an `AnsiString` and then use its `c_str()` method to get a `char*` pointer:

  `fprintf(out, "%s\n", AnsiString(Edit1->Text).c_str());`
- use `fprintf()` with the `%Ls` placeholder instead:

  `fprintf(out, "%ls\n", Edit1->Text.c_str());`
- use `fwprintf()` instead:

  `fwprintf(out, L"%s\n", Edit1->Text.c_str());`
- use a more modern file I/O library, like the standard C++ `std::ofstream`, or the RTL's `TStreaWriter`, etc.

> I have no idea why, but right now it seems to be writing only the first character of the text in Edit1 to the file.

Because you are telling `fprintf()` (via `%s`) to expect an 8bit null-terminated `char*` string, but you are passing it a 16bit `wchar_t*` string instead.  ASCII characters have `0x00` bytes in them in 16bit strings.

> Also if anyone has a link to a good source for best practices for dealing with strings C++Builder 10.1, I would be grateful.

Have you read Embarcadero's [Migration and Upgrade](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center) documentation yet? It has a section on migrating ANSI code to Unicode.